# how to read some data from particular url in android

Tags: android, url

how to read some data from particular url  in android

Comment: @user: what you want, pls sepcify your question clearly, do you want to parse xml????

Comment: or Json? or maybe the html itself?

Answer (score 3):

```
Try this code in your file:

USE 
url = "your url name+filename.jpg,mp3,etc..."
FileName = "/sdcard/savefilename"


try{
            java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new java.net.URL(url).openStream());
            java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(FileName);
            java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int x=0;
            while((x=in.read(data,0,1024))>=0){
                bout.write(data,0,x);               
            }
            fos.flush();
            bout.flush();
            fos.close();
            bout.close();
            in.close();
      }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient to download the content identified by an URL.